# remove class in jquery not functioning

Tags: jquery

My Code..

```
            if($("#edButtonHTML").is(".active"))
            {
                $("#edButtonHTML").removeClass("active");
                $("#edButtonPreview").addClass("active");
            }
```

I need to remove active class from element #edButtonHTML and add to #edButtonPreview
Unfortunately not functionating...Help me

Comment: Are you sure your if condition is satisfied? Put alter statements to check this

Comment: have you checked it using a browser debugging tool like firebug if the class was really removed? Or did you check that the condition really went inside the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if condition to [assuming active is your class name

```
 if($("#edButtonHTML").hasClass("active"))
 {
    $("#edButtonHTML").removeClass("active");
    $("#edButtonPreview").addClass("active");
 }
```

Comment: Its not working for me even i used hasClass i am using newer version of jquery.

Comment: actually .hasClass("active") is a better way for checking a class but .is(".active") also works. I think the question here is, was the condition satisfied or is the element with edButtonHTML that has a class named active found in the page.

Comment: Yes that is true. My First comment is the same question

Answer (score 0):

Don't think the if-statement will resolve. You can always add an alert statement inside the if to check.
Another option to use is hasClass("active"), so

```
if ($("#edButtonHTML").hasClass("active") {
//go on
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is do some old school approach. Put an alert statement inside the if statement to see if it was really raised.

```
        alert("Before if condition.");
        if($("#edButtonHTML").is(".active"))
        {
            alert("Condition was satisfied");
            $("#edButtonHTML").removeClass("active");
            $("#edButtonPreview").addClass("active");
        }
```

Old school but it works for debugging. But you can use firebug, IEDebugbar or any other browser debugging tool to check if your javascript worked fine.

Comment: It shows alert but i doesnt remove class. I heard that jquery new version not function properly sometimes using removeClass

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your HTML, we can't offer a definitive answer. But a couple of suggestions:

1. Use a JavaScript debugger (I like Firebug) to put a break point inside your "if" condition, to see if code execution ever gets there.
2. If you're convinced the remove function isn't working, post a question in a JQuery forum, or submit a bug report on the JQuery site.